# How to play left handed chords in piano and keyboard?

Tags: piano, keyboard

While playing songs from a fake book, I use the left hand bass octave with chord voicing on the right hand if I am playing in piano.

However in keyboard, I can't play the bass octave along with rhythm as it produces a different chord pattern and also there is a possibility of minor chords which I can't play in octaves. What do i do in this case?

Is there any way I can play a piece such that it is suitable both in keyboard and in piano?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the difference is between keyboard and piano playing for you? My "keyboard" is exactly the same as a piano, so it's difficult to understand what you mean by this.

Comment: @NReilingh In keyboard, I am specifically talking about how to play a piece with the rhythm(style) as opposed to the playing a piece in piano. In piano, i would play the octave in the base, but can't do that in keyboard while playing the rhythm(style) as the chords will get messed up.

Comment: It seems we're hitting a bit of a language barrier trying to understand what you're asking. Can you create a recording on soundcloud illustrating the difference between how you play on a piano versus a keyboard?

Comment: Indeed, this requires as much audio and/or notation examples as you can give us if you want a good answer. It's still ambiguous to me as to whether we're talking about arrangement or execution.

Comment: I think the keyboard must be quite a bit shorter than a full 88-keys. This would certainly constrain the options for chord voicing. Or, maybe it has "chord" keys with a built-in arpeggiator... perhaps overlaid with the left end of the keyboard so the bass notes aren't accessible as individual keys. That's going to depend on the exact features of the keyboard. I'm thinking "rhythm(style)" is a mode selection.

Comment: @luserdroog that is especially true for my keyboard (and apparently Aaron's as well. Aaron: my keyboard has two options, which are manual fingering and automatic rhythm/style. I always choose the former. Not sure if your keyboard provides the same feature. In this case i would play the full chords on my left hand, and (as my piano skills are still elementary) i would play either the melody or two notes of the intended chord. Hope this makes sense:)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're talking about the simplified chord fingering which some keyboards offer for auto-accompaniments (aka rhythms/styles). For example, if you press just a C then the auto-accompaniment usually plays a C major chord. The same usually works for any other individual note.

Beyond that, the fingering is completely at the discretion of the manufacturer, and can vary widely from one keyboard to the next. There is no standard that I'm aware of. More importantly, it sometimes bears little or no resemblance to real chords, so there may be no way to make the technique transferrable to a piano or other keyboards.

You will need to check the manual of your keyboard for details, or just experiment and see what happens. If you don't have a hardcopy of the manual anymore then you may be able to find a copy of it or a tutorial online somewhere.

It's worth noting that some keyboards (usually the more expensive ones) offer more than one fingering mode. There may be a 'realistic', 'multi-finger', or 'full-keyboard' mode which is more comparable to real chord voicings.